# Can anyone give share reference for quadrat size in vegetation

Tags: statistics, vegetation

In sampling vegetation, what is the size of a quadrat needed?

And I need a reference too plz.

If the type matters, pick any vegetation all I need is an example of crops and the quadrat size. With reference ofcourse.

Comment: Welcome to Earth Science Stack Exchange! You will get more from the community if you ask a more specific question. What have you found in your research? My quick search turned up lots of info, eg [this](http://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/veg_measure/Modules/Lessons/Module%205(Density)/5_2_Plot-based_Techniques.htm).

Comment: The required quadrat size will depend on the vegetation density and the number of species. You say crops - does this mean you are looking at planted mono-cultures? The ecologists I have worked with use quadrats of varying size that are based in part on their experience and the study questions. You do not want a quadrat so small it doesn't represent the class variability. However, you don't want ones so large that they merge different ecosystems together. For example you may use large quadrats in forests to catch the different tree species but smaller ones in wetlands that vary in space.